# Replacement for IDT70825S/L: Sequential Access / Random Access Memory

Tags: sram

I am building a circuit which needs to sequentially buffer pixels from a VGA signal at 25MHz (using TI's TVP7002) into RAM, and then needs to access pixels out of order given addresses. It looks like there used to be a chip which would allow exactly that ([datasheet](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/idt/70825_DS_33882.pdf)), but it is now obsolete. I am having a lot of trouble finding a suitable replacement; Is there one, and if not how can I duplicate this type of functionality?

Comment: Just use ram faster than 20ns (50MHz). Give the VGA controller access to it in the even cycles and the other device access in the odd cycles. Details left as an exercise... Or, given the tiny size of that RAM, use a few BlockRams in an FPGA. (They are usually dual-ported).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too deep into the varieties of RAM there are, but if you just need the **random** access method, any SRAM will probably do, as 25MHz isn't really *fast* by modern standards (and faster SRAM will still work at slower speeds).

If you need the automatic sequential access: a small PAL or FPGA between RAM and controller will probably do the job of increasing the address you're talking to. However, you'd need to write some HDL to achieve that. Again, 25 MHz isn't fast, so even an ICE40 (for which a Free & Open Source toolchain exists) will do the job.